# C# Upload image and saving as Bitmap Increase size of the image

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bitmap

For uploading image I am using plupload on client side. Then in my controlled I have next logic:

```
public ActionResult UploadFile()
{
    try
    {
       var file = Request.Files.Count > 0 ? Request.Files[0] : null;
       using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream())
       {
           using (var oldImage = new Bitmap(file.InputStream))
           {
               var format = oldImage.RawFormat;
               using (var newImage = ImageUtility.ResizeImage(oldImage, 800, 2000))
               {
                  newImage.Save(fileStream, format);
               }

              byte[] bits = fileStream.ToArray();
            }
       }
    {
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

ImageUtility.ResizeImage Method:

```
public static class ImageUtility
{
    public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap image, int width, int height)
    {
        if (image.Width <= width && image.Height <= height)
        {
            return image;
        }

        int newWidth;
        int newHeight;
        if (image.Width > image.Height)
        {
            newWidth = width;
            newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ((float)width / image.Width));
        }
        else
        {
            newHeight = height;
            newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ((float)height / image.Height));
        }

        var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            return newImage;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue which i have here that Image size is increased.
I uploaded image of 1.62MB and after this controller is called and it creates instance if Bitmap and then save Bitmap to filestream and read bits with "fileStream.ToArray();" I am getting 2.35MB in "bits".

Can anyone tell me what's the reason of increasing the image size after I save it as bitmap. I need Bitmap because I need to check with and height of uploaded image and resize it if I need.

Comment: Changing the file format changes the size of the data, because different image format types store image data differently.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, the bitmap takes up more memory the whatever format the image was in previously because it's uncompressed it stays in that uncompressed format after saving it.

Answer (score 0):

jpeg, png, gif, etc. are compressed and therefore use less bytes tha a bitmap which is uncompressed.

If you just want to save the original image, just save file.InputStream.

If you need to resize, you can use a library to apply jpg/png/etc compression and then save the result.

Comment: Can I then compress Bitmap again?

Comment: You should be able to call `newImage.Save("file.png", ImageFormat.Png);` or `ImageFormat.Jpg`

Answer (score 0):

What is the goal here? Are you merely trying to upload an image? Does it need to be validated as an image? Or are you just trying to upload the file?

If upload is the goal, without any regard to validation, just move the bits and save them with the name of the file. As soon as you do this ...

```
using (var oldImage = new Bitmap(file.InputStream))
```

... you are converting to a bitmap. Here is where you are telling the bitmap what format to use (raw).

```
 var format = oldImage.RawFormat;
```

If you merely want to move the file (upload), you can run the memory stream to a filestream object and you save the bits.

If you want a few checks on whether the image is empty, etc, you can try this page (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1956/NET-Image-Uploading), but realize it is still putting it in an image, which is not your desire if you simply want to save "as is".

Comment: Yes I am merely trying to upload an image, it doesn't need to be validated as an image. But the reason why I am saving is as Bitmap is so I can check Widht and height of the image, and resize it if width > 800 or height > 2000. Please check my question again, i edited it

Comment: Are you only resizing if it is too small? Or are you resizing up, as well. What it appears is you are always sizing to 800 x 2000. If the image is smaller, it will be bigger once resized. That is part of the algorithm. BTW, I would be careful using the .NET bits to resize, as they leave artifacts. If resize is a requirement, then I would consider a better image library, so the images are crisp. Since you have raw, you will have less problems, but you will also deal with larger images.

Comment: I am resizing iz only if it's too big. Never if it too small. So original image will be resized if width is larger then 800 or height larger then 2000 to smaller one. Othervise it will not be resized at all.

And when it's not resized I am getting more Bits, I figure out that's because Bitmap is not compresed. Can I after resizing compress it again?